# Struct unpack strange result

Tags: python, struct, tcp, unpack

I am struggling with a very annoying bug. I have two computers. I send data from one and receive data on the other.

At first I tried the struct fmt, this is how I send it :

```
    # Two chars and three shorts
    fmt = struct.Struct('2B 3h')
    # Two chars and three floats
    fmt2 = struct.Struct('2B 3f')
    message=[0]*5
    message[0] = cmd
    message[1] = 6
    message[2] = d1
    message[3] = d2
    message[4] = d3
    conn.send(fmt.pack(*message))
```

The value is properly unpacked and correct on the client :

```
raw = self.s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
idx = 0
while idx < len(raw):
    length, data = parse(raw, idx)
    idx += length

    cmd, length, x, y, z = fmt.unpack(data)
```

But if I use the second format (fmt2) on both server and client unpack fail. (I took care that d1, d2 and d3 are floats). I tried to unpack the values one by one but I get wrong data for x,y,z.

I have no idea how to solve this and I'm not really familiar with struct.

Thank you

Comment: What are you using to send the data? Just plain sockets? Have you considered using a library which already does this kind of thing? Maybe have a look at some twistedmatrix examples? https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/

Comment: Yes I use plain socket, I'll get a look at your library

Comment: Try to add ">" in your format to specify endianess

Comment: I added struct.Struct('>2B3h') on both sides. I'm still getting nonsense values

Comment: I didn't manage to do anything with unpack. I tried to send json strings and parse it. It's working and so easier.